# How can I find if a column has more than one value per account?

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a database that stores vehicles for specific dealers.  I'm trying to find out if there are any accounts that have multiple vehicle Makes in them.  The data looks something like this:

```
ID   Name           VIN         Make      Type
1    Joes Ford     1123232      Ford      New
1    Joes Ford     3324233      Ford      New
1    Joes Ford     4544543      Ford      New
2    Mikes Chevy   7645655      Chevy     New
2    Mikes Chevy   9865765      Chevy     New
2    Mikes Chevy   2222234      Chevy     New
```

For all of my data I want to find out how which dealers have more than one value in the Make column where the Type is New.  If I run the query on the above data it would come out to zero because each dealer only has one Make.

But if my data looks like this:

```
ID   Name           VIN         Make      Type
1    Joes Ford     1123232      Ford      New
1    Joes Ford     3324233      Volvo      New
1    Joes Ford     4544543      Ford      New
2    Mikes Chevy   7645655      Chevy     New
2    Mikes Chevy   9865765      Acura     New
2    Mikes Chevy   2222234      Dodge     New
```

My results would look like this:

```
ID
1
2
```

because there are two dealers that have more than one Make.

Comment: Group by and Having count(*) > 1

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID
FROM Dealer
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT MAKE)>1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that helps.  I should clarify that Type could be New or Used and I only care where type is new.   I also slightly changed the question so that I could get the list of IDs where there are more than one Make.

Comment: Just add a where clause `where type = new`

Comment: The query didn't work with or without the WHERE statement.  I got zero results and I know for a fact that there are accounts with more than one Make.

Comment: Pretty sure it works. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7d6283/1/0

Comment: @Rob:; this answers the question you asked, and returns the expected results for your sample data (you need to add the `WHERE` clause though, as suggested by Salman A). If you have another question, then you should probably consider asking a new question.